# Create a standalone build for react application using electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-packager

It is my first project in that I'm using electron, I'm dealing with a few problems creating standalone publish from the project.

Here's my electron main.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const electron = require("electron");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app;
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const url = require("url");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false });
  // cm: open app in fullscreen mode
  mainWindow.maximize();
  mainWindow.show();

  // cm: remove default menu bar
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);

  if (isDev) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(
      "http://localhost:3000"
    );
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile("./dist/index.js");
  }

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on("closed", function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

And my package.json scripts are:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . IranFMCG --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"IranFMCG\"",
  },
```

Everything is fine when the react application is running and I'm using "npm run electron" but after running "npm run package-win" and after that when I'm running exe file I am facing errors.

I think that is because I'm not running react app anymore, but I want to use react build files is it possible?

Comment: what errors do you get? Did you run "build" before "package-win"? otherwise your react files are probably missing in the packaged electron app. react electron boiler plate: https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react